# Why this function causes non-stop printing?

Tags: c, printing, infinite

Hello a friend of mine shown me this piece of code to make a point about array/stack bound checking.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo() {
    unsigned long long a[1];
    a[3] -= 5;
    printf("Print me!\n");    
}

int main(){ 
    foo();
    return 0;    
}
```

When I run this code, it keeps printing "Print me!\n" all the time, it just doesn't stop. I've compiled code with MingW 64bit. What's happening here? I'd like someone to explain me, why it keeps printing the text.

Comment: No, it doesn't cause non-stop printing!

Comment: Undefined behaviour means just that - that the behaviour is *undefined*.  Anything can happen.

Comment: It alters the return address on the stack.  The value 5 is significant because that's the length of the CALL machine code instruction.  So when the function returns, it jumps back to the function call.  Hacks like these don't often reproduce well.

Comment: @Raj Maybe it depends on a compiler... I've compiled it with MingW 64bit.

Comment: @Amas, undefined behaviour almost certainly depends on the compiler.  In fact, it could even depend on each compilation or even each run of the resulting binary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You damage thread stack by command `a[3] -= 5;` because changing var out of array range. The behavior is totaly unpredictable and can be different on other systems. I think you just modify return address on stack to call printf

If you want to understand - use disassembler.

Answer (score 1):

You are changing values outside your stackframe in foo().

Specifically, you are subtracting 5 from the return address (if this is normal x86-32 calling conventions)

If the foo() call in main is compiled into something like

`call ebp-126` (call short offset) the instruction is 5 bytes long.

Thus, the return will go to the call, and not to after the call. And the call will be executed again.

This is about as anti-portable and undefined as code gets, though, since it depends on both calling conventions and the specific instructions emitted by the compiler.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be a [stack buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow).

You are referencing an undefined index in the stack array `a`. This could be overwriting the return address on the stack.

When the function `return`s to the `main` function, it is most likely executing `foo` again, since the return address is probably getting set to the value before the function was called by the `- 5` operation.

Comment: Correct principle, but actually it returns back to main but the address is changed to before the `foo()` call, so it gets executed again. Undefined behaviour indeed.

Comment: Thanks for that. I meant `foo` by "print function"--since this is the function that evokes the `printf`. I have clarified the answer.